# Gene products of recessive/mutated alleles

Tags: proteins, gene-expression

I probably would not cite a specific example, but some recessive allele work by encoding for the non-functional form of an enzyme. While the dominant allele encodes for sufficient levels of functional enzyme that the dominant phenotype is present in heterozygous individuals. Will the individual have many uselessly non-functional proteins floating around along with everything else?